# Sidekiq eats too much RAM with no jobs running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memory-leaks, sidekiq

Is that normal that Sidekiq eats the 25% of my RAM even if there are no jobs running (0/10 busy)?[image]

I'm using jemalloc as suggested online: it seems that the consumption has decreased a bit, but not so much.

Comment: Why you trigger so many Sidekiq process? I can see from your screenshot at least 15 processes, that's the problem. How many jobs you need to process daily or what is the peak number?

Comment: @Vibol There are at least 35 jobs daily, but there are other webapps that process less jobs with the same number of processes and they do not eat up so much RAM.

Comment: Sidekiq run jobs from queue, so there's no need to have that many processes, 1 process is enough. Do you run 15 processes intentionally or by mistake?

Comment: htop shows all threads by default, those aren’t unique processes.

Answer (score 1):

RAM usage is a function of your app code and the gems you load. Use a profiler like derailed_benchmarks to profile RAM usage in your app. Lowering the concurrency from 10 to 5 might help a little.